# HTML Auto-Refresh a DIV loading an RSS Feed (text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I want to make it so that the code automatically refreshes a DIV that displays an RSS Feed from last.fm to display the current music playing on my spotify.

This:

```
<script>
<div id="rss" style="height:25px;">
<iframe src="http://us1.rssfeedwidget.com/getrss.php?time=1400505489628&amp;x=http%3A%2F%2Fws.audioscrobbler.com%2F1.0%2Fuser%2Flukeassassin%2Frecenttracks.rss&amp;bc=333333&amp;bw=1&amp;bgc=transparent&amp;m=1&amp;it=false&amp;t=(default)&amp;tc=333333&amp;ts=15&amp;tb=transparent&amp;il=true&amp;lc=FF0000&amp;ls=28&amp;lb=false&amp;id=false&amp;dc=333333&amp;ds=14&amp;idt=false&amp;dtc=284F2D&amp;dts=12" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" align="center" style="border:0; padding:0; margin:0; width:600px; height:500px; text-align:center;" id="rssOutput"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

This is what it displays on the page:

[image]

Comment: why are you closing 2 `</div>` in your code?

Comment: In the coding above I had an open div that this div was inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to fill the div with the information you want.
Then using an interval you can reload the contents every X seconds

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/T7cZU/3/

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ReloadData()
    setInterval(function(){ReloadData()}, 1500);
});

function ReloadData(){
     $( "#result" ).load( "http://numbersapi.com/random/trivia", function() {});   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="result">
    Original content
</div>
```

or you could simply reload your iframe:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
}, 1500);
```

Updated fiddle with both methods of updating: http://jsfiddle.net/T7cZU/5/

Comment: for the bottom one, how do/would you add an interval?

Comment: the first one works, but then when it refreshes it says: {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: use jsfiddle in internet explorer, it dosent work well in firefox or chrome. Also updated answer with new fiddle that updates iframe too.

Comment: Is there a way to make it stop flashing on and off? like only update If its changed?